# Spark SQL- Dynamically select columns which are not nulls in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark-sql

I want to select the columns which contains values other than NULL. Suppose I have a table abc:

```
SnapshotDate    CreationDate    Country Region  CloseDate   Probability BookingAmount   RevenueAmount   SnapshotDate1   CreationDate1   CloseDate1
        null            null       null   null       null   25  882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   25  882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
        null            null       null   null       null   0   882000  0            null            null         null
```

Then I would want to select Only Probability, BookingAmount and RevenueAmount columns as they contains some values other than null and ignore the rest of the column that contains only null values.

I tried doing something like -
select * from abc where SnapshotDate != null and CreationDate != null and ..... 
But that does not help as it will look for each row.

NOTE:- 
Is there something like - sqlContext.sql("select case when col1 is null then dont select it else select it end) x from abc")

I am using spark 1.6.1

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could collect first row check for non null values and get the name of column then call select on your previous dataframe. Done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove NULL columns in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324762/remove-null-columns-in-spark-sql)